# Memory utilization for instance variable vs. method variable in Java

Tags: java

Out of two below implementation (HashMap object place been changed), which one take less memory, and when memory will get released ?

```
public class ValidateA implements SessionBean {

    private HashMap auditData = null;

    private void validater (String Record) {
        this.auditData = null;
        //operation this.auditData = ...
    }
}

public class ValidateB implements SessionBean {

    private void validater (String Record) {
        HashMap auditData = null;
        //operation auditData = ..
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The memory used will be roughly the same (exactly the same if you only have one instance of `ValidateA` in your application and one thread).

The memory **for the `auditData` reference itself** will be released:

- In `ValidateA`, when `ValidateA` instance itself becomes eligible for garbage collection)
- In `ValidateB`, at the end of the method

The memory **for the `HashMap` instance** will be released (become eligible for GC) when it's no longer referenced from any place - assuming you have no other references to the map except for `auditData`:

- In `ValidateA`, when you set `auditData = null`, when you run the method again (overwriting previous `auditData`), or when `ValidateA` instance itself becomes eligible for GC
- In `ValidateB`, at the end of the method

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually, the logic bit complex and I am not fully aware of this. I have asked this question because during complete we sometime get outofmemory exception.
Currently we are using implemention like ValidateA, but from your reply, if we use ValidateB, HashMap will be ready for GC after the method itself, and since we have more method inside class, we don't have to wait till ValidateA, itself become eligible for GC.